# Adaptable statistical power

Tags: hypothesis-testing, algorithms, statistical-power

In software development, **unit testing** is (basically) executing an algorithm with a fixed input and test if the output is as expected. Example : "test that MyFactorial(4) returns 24" where "MyFactorial" is a piece of code you have written.

Unit testing is used very often to detect regressions : a bug that wasn't here before suddenly happens after a developer modified the code. It is most often executed recurrently by a server (say daily) and it sends you an email when it fails "MyFactorial(4)=-3. Expected 24. Something's wrong.".

We want to test a random algorithm that has a certain known probability $\alpha$ (95%) to give the right answer (on a certain fixed input) because it uses random methods. The k-means, EM are good examples : the probability to reach the global optimum is not 100%. We don't want to receive an e-mail in 5% cases : false positives.

Unlike in a classical statistical test, the server can decide to run the algorithm as many times as it wants and it can decide to **adapt this number** depending on the situation. For example :

- "false result" -> retry
- "false result"-> retry
- "false result" -> retry
- ...a few times
- send an e-mail "p-value that nothing is wrong is one out of zillions"

In a way you have virtually unlimited statistical power. We want to design a testing procedure that detects deviation from the null hypothesis : "the algorithm succeeds in >95% cases". We want :

- minimal amount of false positive : (almost never) an email when nothing is wrong.
- a good power.
- we also want to save computer resources : no need to run the algorithm many many times when we are quite sure nothing is wrong.

How would you design a testing procedure where you can optimize and rigorously control these requirements ? How to adapt the number of times the algorithm is executed ? And is it truly useful ?